# Function Code coverage not 100%

Tags: php, code-coverage, codeception

[image]

How should the following be fixed? My function here is marked as 0% coverage. The trailing brace fails and I have 0% coverage.

If i add in the else `return null`, that fails (understandably - as it shouldn't fail).  If I keep the null and put it all on one line like so:

```
if($this->save()){ return true; } return null;
```

Then it passes. I'm new to testing and not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Maybe `return null;` was never reached!?

Comment: What if you return false instead of null ? if($this->save()){ return true; } return false;

Comment: Cant really say, what i found was this `coverage functionality is provided by the Xdebug extension` so its not PHPUnit itself, it get teh infromation from xdebug. Whatever i cant really help sry.

Comment: Some testing frameworks have annotations for explicitly ignoring certain lines or blocks of code during code coverage analysis (e.g. PHPUnit). Don't know about Codeception though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% code coverage means you are testing every single outcome of each function. Your `return null` line is marked as not covered because no test of yours branches to this line.

In order to mark it as covered you will need a test where `$this->save()` returns `false` and test that your method returns `null` like it should.

In some cases, getting 100% code coverage is impossible, or leads to some very stupid/weird looking tests. In these cases you can simply ignore testing that particular line.

Edit: If you rewrite your code to return `true` or `false`, instead of `true` and `null`, you could rewrite your method to this:

```
$expression = new Expression('SYSDATE');
$this->last_login = $expression;
return $this->save();
```

This code should have 100% code coverage.